# explicit form of partitioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a partitioned matrix:

$D=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b' \\
b & C
\end{array}
 \right)$

where $a$ is a scalar, $b$ is $m \times 1$ and $C$ is $m \times m$.
I want to compute 
$a-b'C^{-1}b$ explicitly without computing the inverse $C^{-1}$. From different point of view, I want to derive the (1,1) element of $D^{-1}$, given by $D^{11}=(a-b'C^{-1}b)^{-1}$.

Is it possible?

Comment: Most of the time performing a solve like $C^{-1}b$ is much easier than computing the full inverse $C^{-1}$, and this is all that is required here. The standard method would be to compute an LU factorization $C=LU$, then perform two backsolves to compute $LUx=b$. Another possibility is to perform the solve iteratively, with a preconditioned Krylov method like MINRES with an incomplete cholesky factorization. There are a lot of possibilities to make this solve fast depending on the details of the matrix C.

Comment: Many thanks. But, what I want to know is how to derive the form of $b'C^{-1}b$ analytically, not numerically.

Comment: Is that really $D$ to the eleventh power?

Comment: Sorry, $D^{11}$ denotes the (1,1) element of $D^{-1}$.